# local anchor links not working in chrome desktop browser

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, google-chrome

I would like to use this greenfair CSS template (https://www.free-css.com/free-css-templates/page229/greenfair) but the anchor links in the navbar do not work in chrome (they do work in firefox and IE). What can I do to fix this? You can use the live-demo on the page to reproduce.

One example is this #welcome anchor:

```
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse zero_mp" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right main_menu">
                                 <li><a href="#welcome">about</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>


<!--Start of welcome section-->
    <section id="welcome">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                    <div class="wel_header">
                        <h2>welcome to green fair</h2>
                        <p>Our Green Fire Organization is one of the non profit organization near you. Get our services like</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <!--End of row-->
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-3">
                    <div class="item">
                        <div class="single_item">
                            <div class="item_list">
                                <div class="welcome_icon">
                                    <i class="fa fa-leaf"></i>
                                </div>
                                <h4>eco system</h4>
                                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, eu qui modo expetendis reformidans ex sit set appetere sententiae seo eum in simul homero.</p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <!--End of col-md-3-->
                <div class="col-md-3">
                    <div class="item">
                        <div class="single_item">
                            <div class="item_list">
                                <div class="welcome_icon">
                                    <i class="fa fa-refresh"></i>
                                </div>
                                <h4>recycling</h4>
                                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, eu qui modo expetendis reformidans ex sit set appetere sententiae seo eum in simul homero.</p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <!--End of col-md-3-->
                <div class="col-md-3">
                    <div class="item">
                        <div class="single_item">
                            <div class="item_list">
                                <div class="welcome_icon">
                                    <i class="fa fa-tint"></i>
                                </div>
                                <h4>water refine</h4>
                                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, eu qui modo expetendis reformidans ex sit set appetere sententiae seo eum in simul homero.</p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <!--End of col-md-3-->
                <div class="col-md-3">
                    <div class="item">
                        <div class="single_item">
                            <div class="item_list">
                                <div class="welcome_icon">
                                    <i class="fa fa-cog"></i>
                                </div>
                                <h4>solar system</h4>
                                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, eu qui modo expetendis reformidans ex sit set appetere sententiae seo eum in simul homero.</p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <!--End of col-md-3-->
            </div>
            <!--End of row-->
        </div>
        <!--End of container-->
    </section>
    <!--end of welcome section-->
```

Comment: you have to provide code sample in your question instead of posting an external link

Comment: done it. But I don't think the error is inside this snippet. The Problem is that I don't know where to look for it.

Comment: I'm seeing lots of errors in the console when I try the live demo. Particularly, **Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'LayoutMode' of undefined
    at cells-by-row.js:1**

Comment: this error can be fixed by inverting the include order of isotype.pkgd and cells-by-row scripts

Comment: I switched the include order of those files and the error described by Barmar is gone. Unfortunately the problem with the not working anchors persits.

Comment: I updated jquery and other scroll modules and was able to scroll on google chrome. I gave all the details in my answer. please check and let me know ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To fix the issue, you need to update jquery, jquery.localScroll and jquery.scrollTo to be compatible with recent versions of chrome.

I used the following versions of the modules with your css template, and everything works fine:

- jquery-2.2.4.js
- jquery.scrollTo.min.js version 2.0
- jquery.localScroll.min.js version 2.0

Here are the links where you can get them:

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.js" integrity="sha256-iT6Q9iMJYuQiMWNd9lDyBUStIq/8PuOW33aOqmvFpqI=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

[jquery.scrollTo](https://github.com/flesler/jquery.scrollTo)
[jquery.localScroll](https://github.com/flesler/jquery.localScroll)

Also, there is a small error in the index.html file:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'LayoutMode' of undefined

You can fix it by inverting the include order of cells-by-row.js and isotope.pkgd.min.js files.

Comment: I updated the 2 modules in the js subdirectory and inserted your line from above containing the link to jquery-2.2.4. It did not change anything. But I found out that when I remove (rename, comment out...) jquery.localScroll.min.js the links work in chrome. They then just do not scroll softly.

Comment: Oh and of course I removed jquery-1.12.3.min.js from the code

Comment: you need to update the 3 modules and it will scroll softly. I am running chrome 73.
Regarding jquery.scrollTo.min.js and jquery.localScroll.min.js, you need to replace the files with the updated versions in js folder

Comment: It works when I copy everything to my local windows machine. It does still not work on my linux server even after a reboot. But that's another problem now. Thank you.

Comment: Great! However, it should be working when you deploy the files to your Linux server because this javascript is executed on the client side which means the browser. Make sure you cleaned your browser cache and the source code of the html page to make sure the changes are really applied.